# Trouble understanding Lax method for KDV equation for inverse scattering method

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

I am trying to learn the Lax pair condition on my own so that I can eventually learn the inverse scattering method. I am following a paper by Tuncay Aktosun (*"Inverse scattering transform and the theory of solitons"* uou can find the paper [here](https://fermat.uta.edu/preprints/springer15.pdf)).  I am trying to arrive at his equation \eqref{4}, but I am having some trouble (from here on, all equations are numbered as in the cited paper).  Please also correct my thinking if I have made a mistake in my understanding along the way.  I am using the same equation numbers as in the paper for reference.

I start with the Lax equation
$$
L_{t} + [L,A] = 0.\label{1}\tag{4.3}
$$
For the KdV equation, we try the Schrödinger equation (linear ODE) and hope that it yields a good Lax pair from which I can solve for the Lax operator $A$.  The KDE equation is
$$
u_{t} - 6uu_{x} + u_{xxx} = 0,
$$
and since their exists a third partial derivative in the KdV equation, I am assuming this is why the author says we can assume that the operator $A$ takes the form
$$
\alpha_{3}\partial^{3}_{x}+\alpha_{2}\partial^{2}_{x}+\alpha_{1}\partial_{x}+\alpha_{0},\label{3}\tag{4.5}$$
as this assumption contains the third partial derivative as well.  Using
$$
L=-\partial_{x}^{2} + u(x,t), \label{2}\tag{4.4}
$$ which is the Schrödinger operator, I substitute \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} into \eqref{1}.

Unfortunately when trying to work this out, I am aware that all the coefficients $\alpha$'s of the differential operator \eqref{3} could depend on both $x$ and $t$, the spatial and temporal coordinates.  I cannot see how to arrive at the following equation
$$
()\partial^{5}_{x}+()\partial^{4}_{x} + ()\partial^{3}_{x} + ()\partial^{2}_{x} + \partial_{x} + () = 0 \label{4}\tag{4.6} 
$$
where $()$ is supposed to denote the coefficients.  I don't see where $u_{t}$ vanishes (from \eqref{2} $L_{t} = u_{t}$), nor how to treat the derivatives of the $\alpha$ terms since $\alpha(x,t)$ is possible, as stated in the paper.  I may indeed be making some silly mistake, but I would really appreciate some detail on how one could arrive at equation \eqref{4} so that I could further understand the method properly.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, would I be correct in saying that nobody really knows what a good Lax pair would be for an integrable non-linear partial differential equation?  One just hopes that they find a good linear ODE that happens to work for the non-linear PDE when they solve for $A$ using the Lax equation?